# Spring boot: How to persist one-to-many relation separately using Repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes, **department** and **employees**. They have a **one-to-many** relationship, i.e. one department can have many employees.

Employee cannot exist without a department.
Department can have 0 to n employees.

I get lists of both of these items... These lists can contain new entries and updated entries.

My question is, how do I go about it?

1. Save / merge departments independently
2. Save / merge employees after step 1. independently (making sure, the department ID employee has, exists in department table)

OR

1. Save / merge departments with a `Set<>` of employees?

OR

Is there another way to do this that I haven't thought about yet?

Comment: Your requirements are vague, and you haven't tried anything apparently. So, try something, then try harder, and if it doesn't do what you want, then come back here, post all the relevant code, explain precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: I have tried both of these, but I am not sure which is better.

Comment: That depends on your use case. The question is if you really need a Set of employees in the department.

Comment: Yes, I do need a Set of employees, because when I fetch a Department I get the employees automatically in set, so I will never have to fetch employees directly

Comment: In that case merge the department with the set of employees.

Comment: How many employees per department will you have?

Comment: One department can have up to 10 or 12 employees

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two patterns called 'Repository' and 'Aggregate', they are from Eric Evans **Domain Driven Design** book, and it is the best practice to use one of them.

### Repository pattern

- two independent entities (department and employee)
- no JPA relations (`@OneToMany`) between entities
- `employee` just contains it's `departmentId` field
- two repositories (`departmentRepo`, `employeeRepo`)

If you have to get employee's department it should be like:

```
department = departmentRepo.findById(employee.departmentId)
```

Saving entities also done using their repositories independently:

```
newDepartment = departmentRepo.save(new Department())
newEmployee = employeeRepo.save(new Employee(newDepartment.id))
```

### Aggregate pattern

Unlike two repositories and absence of connection between entities aggregate pattern uses:

- ONE repository (`departmentRepo` in this case)
- `department` entity has `@OneToMany` connection to `employees` (department contains employees).

In this case to fetch employees you have to use department repository:

```
employees = departmentRepo.findById(departmentId).employees
```

The same thing for saving: you should save department to save changes in employee.

### Recap

Any mixes of these patterns (most common: two repos and JPA relationship between entities) lead to really hard maintain problems in future.

In most of the cases, I prefer Repository pattern: repository per entity, and absence of relations between entities.

In your case I would pick Repository pattern.

Comment: but that does mean that in case of **Repository Pattern**  I can't enforce data integrity at database level, right?

Comment: You still can create constraints in DB. But often it is not needed (for example it makes harder to test, because you have to create too many entities to satisfy all the constrains). What you can NOT use is cascade deletion, but it is also rare case and can be handled 'manually'.

Answer (score 1):

You can have entity classes defined like below:

```
@Entity
public class Department {
  @NotNull
  @Id
  private String depId;
  private String depName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
  orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<Employee> employees;
}

@Entity
public class Employee {

  @Id
  private String employeeId;
  private String employeeName;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "dep_id", nullable = true)
  private Department department;
}
```

Keeping department nullable in employee and employee in department. You'll need to have repository defined over these entities to fetch/save.
Also if you are going to use a set of employee make sure it overrides hashcode() and equals() methods of object class.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a department field in the employee class. Whenever you change the association between an employee and a department, you need to set employee.department, and add/remove the employee to/from the corresponding department.employees collection.

Then you need only to save the departments, assuming, that the CascadeType is properly set for the department.employees collection.