# Data persistence patterns and working with relationships using Springboot/hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, design-patterns, relationship, repository-pattern

I'm trying to wrap my head around persistence and data retrieval using springboot.
Let's say i have a **User**(email,password) entity and it's following relationships

A **User** can have multiple authorities (or privileges, used for authorization)

A **User** can have one **UserProfile**(username,birthdate...etc) for storing different informations about the user

The typical springboot CRUD example would suggest to create the entities and a repository for each entity and use the **@OneToOne**, **@OneToMany**...etc relationships on the entities but doesn't this approach mixes both the **Repository** and **Aggregate** pattern which can lead to very hard to maintain code ?

What are the best practices/patterns used in an actual springboot application to manage persistence in an easy and maintainable way ?

**EDIT**
Link to the post which clearly states that mixing the repository/aggregate approach can lead to hard to maintain code :
[Spring boot: How to persist one-to-many relation separately using Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763093/spring-boot-how-to-persist-one-to-many-relation-separately-using-repository)

Also from my personal experience i saw examples of Springboot applciation managing entities without using relationship annotations (@OneTone, OnetoMany...etc) which resembles the Repository pattern.

The main problem i'm having with relationship annotations is that they tend to be tricky to work with and need more boilerplate code to make them work and avoid problems such as N+1 queries, infnite serialization recursion and bi-directional relationships. What are your thoughts about this, is there a more straightforward way of managing persistence in a springboot application nowadays ?

Comment: I'd say it's pretty common to combine ideas from multiple design patterns within the same code.

Comment: i saw another stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763093/spring-boot-how-to-persist-one-to-many-relation-separately-using-repository that clearly states that combining repository and aggregate pattern can lead to hard to maintain code

Comment: Interesting. Is that post saying that within a single application you should not have some entities that are stand-alone and others that have relations between each other? That seems unnecessarily strict. E.g., it can often be helpful to represent a primary to foreign key relation within the domain objects themselves (e.g., using @OneToMany).

Comment: No it just states that mixing relationships annotations with the repository pattern leads to hard to maintain code. I feel that the use of relationships (hibernate annotations) does add a lot of complexity and the entities get harder to reason about when we model them as "Objetcs". Some use MyBatis (a query mapper in a nutshell) and primary key constraints, no foreign key whatsoever. I also red on the internet that some devs tend to avoid relationship annotations like the plague due to how tricky they can be, but i'm stil confused about the most efficient and maintainable approach

Comment: I see. Sounds like you're describing the object-relational paradigm mismatch. MyBatis seems to not always require mapping to objects, so perhaps a good choice if you want to avoid that - though it seems to make heavy use of xml, which has its own drawbacks.

Comment: There's also the option of avoiding strictly relational dbrms in favor of a multi-paradigm option, such as [SurrealDB](https://surrealdb.com/), [EdgeDB](https://www.edgedb.com/), [Fauna](https://fauna.com/home) or [xata](https://xata.io/). Not sure if any integrate well w/Spring yet, though.

Comment: Mybatis actually can be used with annotations on it's last versions i think so there's that. For the database systems i knew about faunaDB, but the purpose of my questioning isn't the relational paradigm it's more about figuring out the most efficient way to work with it in an unbloated and maintainable maintain way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example design you can create;

First `User` entity;

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_authority",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id"))
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();

}
```

`UserProfile` entity;

```
@Entity
@Data
public class UserProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthdate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
}
```

And the last entity is `Authority`;

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Authority {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Then you can create your repository classes and service layer from these entities. `OneToMany` relationship between `User` and `UserProfile`, with the user field in `UserProfile` serving as the foreign key and also `ManyToMany` relationship between `User` and `Authority`, with a join table named `user_authority` to manage the relationship. `CascadeType.ALL` on the profiles field in `User` to ensure that when a user is deleted, all associated `UserProfiles` will be also deleted.

Comment: Great answer. Considering “A User can have one UserProfile(username,birthdate...etc) for storing different informations about the user”, I don’t understand why you have set this relationship as @OneToMany? Surely it’s @OneToOne?

Comment: As far as i know in your example you are mixing Repository and Aggregate pattern. plz refer to the *EDIT* in my first post, i added more details to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in Spring Boot you create repository per entity and entities are connected by JPA annotations. This creates rather clean architecture - you fetch data from given repository to obtain concrete entities.

Of course, those entities can have relations. You can fetch them right away with join, you can fetch them in a lazy manner with FetchType.LAZY, you can combine calls of few repositories to obtain desired data. Then simple entities can become such aggregates.

Comment: This is the typical approach we can find in blog posts and tutorials, if you see this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763093/spring-boot-how-to-persist-one-to-many-relation-separately-using-repository, the accepted answer clearly states that mixing the two approaches can lead to hard to maintain code.